# How to send multipart formdata from remote function api?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, rest-api, webservices

I am trying to build the multipart request on client side itself because to avoid the need to send the files back to apex for processing. Also at a time 10 files needs to be sent via rest api, so sending them to apex for firing rest is another issue.

This is my remoteFunction.

```
$('#input-b6').on('filelock', function (event, filestack, extraData) {
            var strFiles = "";
            Object.keys(blob).forEach(function(key) {
                var r = new FileReader();
                console.log(key, blob[key]);
                sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
                    url : 'https://localrestapi.herokuapp.com/consumeFiles',
                    onSuccess : successCallBack,
                    onFailure : errorCallBack,
                    method : 'POST',
                    requestHeaders : 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
                    async : true,
                    requestData : 'filename: ' +r.readAsBinaryString(blob[key]),
                    timeout : 120000
                });
            });
        });
```

I have written and hosted a spring boot service which accepts the multipart form data, it works when i hit the service via postman. 
But when I try to hot it via Javascript in Visualforce page:

This is the error I get :

```
"{"timestamp":"2019-06-30T08:45:26.461+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Current request is not a multipart request","path":"/consumeFiles"}"
```

I think I the `requestData` should change, but not sure what to pass there? ANy ideas?

**Update**

```
            Object.keys(filesBase64).forEach(function (key) {
                console.log(key, filesBase64[key]);

                var data = new FormData();
                data.append('filename', filesBase64[key]);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'https://localrestapi.herokuapp.com/consumeFiles', true);
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    // do something to response
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                };
                xhr.send(data);
            });
```

The console.log does not gets printed out. And getting this console error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localrestapi.herokuapp.com/consumeFiles' from origin 'https://nagesingh-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` Though the files gets passed to the rest repository.

Comment: You are sending data to apex or some other endpoint?
`https://localrestapi.herokuapp.com/consumeFiles`

Comment: That's external endpoint, which I have hosted as a spring boot application. The endpoint wont open but I have written a RestController which accepts post method.

Comment: cool, then, do a HttpRequest in JS then, you dont need to use remoteFunction.

Comment: If I dont use remoteFucntion then the callback method of xhr request does not gets call back. Updated the question. But the files goes via rest.

Comment: Ok, so cross origin support had to be from server side, I changed my spring boot application to support cross origin and now it works fine : 

`@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://nagesingh-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com")`

@PranayJaiswal You can post answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualforce remoting, remoteFunction, are used to call Apex on the Platform. If you wanna call any third party site from javascript then do a normal AJAX call.

Also, as it will be a cross-origin request from javascript so make sure the end-server supports CORS from SF domain.